# c# - Add Object to specific Index on List

Tags: c#, linq, list

I've been spending hours to find a way to insert item to the Object in my List. 
This is what i've done.

```
data = await (from iw in _context.InvestorWallets
                              join m in memberdata on iw.investorid equals m.id
                              where _context.InvestorDeposit.Any(item => item.investordepositid == iw.transactionid) ||
                             _context.InvestorWithdrawal.Any(item => item.withdrawalid == iw.transactionid) ||
                             _context.InstallmentPaymentDistribution.Any(item => item.paymentdistributionid == iw.transactionid)
                              select new InvestorWalletsViewModel()
                              {
                                  username = m.userName,
                                  fullname = m.fullName,
                                  isActive = m.isActive,
                                  memberType = m.memberType,
                                  memberTypeName = m.memberTypeName,
                                  emailAddress = m.emailAddress,
                                  trxdate = iw.trxdate,
                                  trxdesc = iw.trxdesc,
                                  debit = iw.acounttype.ToLower() == "db" ? iw.amount : 0,
                                  credit = iw.acounttype.ToLower() == "cr" ? iw.amount : 0,
                                  investorid = iw.investorid,
                                  investorwalletid = iw.investorwalletid,
                                  transactiontype =
                                    (
                                        iw.transactiontype.ToLower() == "dep" ? "Deposit" :
                                        iw.transactiontype.ToLower() == "wit" ? "Withdrawal" :
                                        iw.transactiontype.ToLower() == "rep" ? "IB-1610043 - Repayment" : "REGULER"
                                    ),
                                  paymentdistributionid =
                                    (
                                        iw.transactiontype.ToLower() == "rep" ? iw.transactionid??0 : 0
                                    ),
                                  details = new List<InvestorWalletsViewModelDetail>(), // <-- I want to insert some object to this list
                                  previousbalance = iw.previousbalance
                              }).Distinct().ToListAsync();

//This is to retrieve data from another table, based on data
var data2 = (from i in _context.InstallmentPaymentDistributionDetails.Where(p => p.amount > 0)
                             where data.Any(d => d.paymentdistributionid == i.paymentdistributionid)
                             select i).Distinct().ToList();

//I used ForEach to itterate through the List, and fill the object
data2.ForEach(d =>
{
    var x = data.Find(z => z.paymentdistributionid == d.paymentdistributionid);
    if (x == null) return;

//This is where I insert the value to the List
    x.details.Add(new InvestorWalletsViewModelDetail //This code right here, it insert the value to all rows in the List, i just want to add the value to the specific row in the List
    {
        actualpayment = d.amount,
        installmentfeetype_name = d.installmentfeetype_name
    });
});
```

}

As you can see on my **ForEach**, I insert the value to the details (List inside List). But, what hapenned is, It did insert the value to the List, but it inserted the value to **ALL** row in List, when it should only insert the value to the particular row / index. I just want to insert the value to the **specific row** in the List.

Anyhelp will be appreciated guys,

Thanks

Comment: Is iterating through the list data2 necessary to fill the object?? Is it not possible to find the record from the list data2 and set the value from the object without iterating through it??

Comment: hmm, do you mean without foreach?

Comment: Yess...just grab the row and insert the object...

Comment: @gkb, no luck man, i tried to inject to specific index, and the result was all the details object in the list filled up with the value

Answer (score 0):

Could convert your list to an arraylist and then use the built in method to insert at a given index.

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(list);
arrayList.insert(index, val);
```

Comment: sorry, not like that bro

Comment: what condition are you looking for in your list when inserting the value?

Answer (score 0):

How about using Skip() and Take()?

You skip the amount of rows you want to omit, then take 1 element. This will return you a list of your object, containing one element.

```
int yourRowIndex = 47; // just an example
x.details.Skip(yourRowIndex).Take(1).ToList().Add(new InvestorWalletsViewModelDetail
{
    actualpayment = d.amount,
    installmentfeetype_name = d.installmentfeetype_name
});
```

the ToList() extention might not be required.

Comment: The row should be grabbed based on a matching condition like - d.paymentdistributionid == i.paymentdistributionid. And not by some offset value...how would you change the yourRowIndex dynamically to fetch the exact row??